# From where should acumatica get the warehouse and location in shipment and lotSerial number?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am getting the "Lot/serial nbr ('anyNumber') can not found in the system", why am i getting this?
From shipment screen i have transferred the inventory to another warehouse/location with same LotSerialNumber exist in SOShipLine. transfer inventory using InventoryTransfer Graph.

Now after a operation i am trying to transfer inventory back to  a warehouse/location with same LotSerialNumber, But some time i am getting "Lot/serial nbr ('anyNumber') can not found in the system" error, How to resolve issue?

Answer (score 0):

The system is not picking the LotRecord up from the PK. You can create the record before pushing the Key or focus on the Allocations function.

Comment: Lot number already exist, but getting the error. As i mention above when i move inventory from shipment to a location/warehouse then i am doing some operation then after i am moving to another warehouse & location, i got this error. specially serialized stock items.

Comment: Hi Amit, can you please copy your code onto the question.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315182/lot-serial-nbr-anynumber-can-not-found-in-the-system-why-am-i-getting-thi