# "Lot/serial nbr ('anyNumber') can not found in the system", why am i getting this?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

"Lot/serial nbr ('anyNumber') can not found in the system", why am i getting this when transfer inventory from a location to another?
1) Transferred inventory from SHIPMENT location/warehouse to another location warehouse.
2) then transferring again from above location warehouse to another warehouse/location. then got error.

```
        INTransferEntry transferGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INTransferEntry>();
        INRegister reg = new INRegister();
        reg.SiteID = lotDetail.WarehouseID;
        reg.ToSiteID = distribution.ToWarehouseID;
        reg.TransferType = Order.Current.TranType;
        reg.DocType = INDocType.Transfer;
        reg.TranDate = DateTime.Now;
        reg.TotalQty = distribution.Qty;

        reg = transferGraph.transfer.Insert(reg);

        INTran tran = new INTran();

        tran.INTransitQty = distribution.Qty;
        tran.InventoryID = Order.Current.InventoryID;
        tran.ToLocationID = distribution.ToLocationID;
        tran.ToSiteID = distribution.ToWarehouseID;
        tran.TranType = INTranType.Transfer;
        tran.InvtMult = INTranType.InvtMult(tran.TranType);
        tran.Qty = distribution.Qty;
        tran.ReasonCode = distribution.ReasonCode;
        tran.SiteID = lotDetail.WarehouseID;
        tran.LocationID = lotDetail.LocationID;
        tran.TranDesc = distribution.Description;
        tran.LotSerialNbr = lotDetail.LotSerNumVal;
        tran = transferGraph.transactions.Insert(tran);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the INTranSplit DAC, it links the Lot Tracking with the INTran DAC to manage the existing Lots linked to the INItem